# Method returning null pointer error

Tags: java

There is the error I am getting

```
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
  at StudentGrades.getMinimum(StudentGrades.java:54)
  at StudentClient.main(StudentClient.java:14)
```

I did not find any method that i set a null.

I tried using median method but still gets me this same error.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class StudentGrades {

Random randomNumber = new Random();
int numberofStudents;
int grade;
int[] grades;
int sum = 0;

public StudentGrades(int studentNumber) {
    numberofStudents = studentNumber;
    int[] grades = new int[numberofStudents];
    for (int i = 0; i < numberofStudents; i++) {
        grades[i] = randomNumber.nextInt(101);
        Arrays.sort(grades);

    }

}

public int getNumberStudents() {
    return numberofStudents;
}

public int[] getStudentGrades() {
    int[] temp = new int[grades.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
        temp[i] = grades[i];
    }
    return temp;
}

public void setStudentGrades(int n) {
    grade = n;
}

public double getAverage() {
    for (int i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
        sum = +grades[i];
    }
    double average = (double) sum / numberofStudents;
    return average;
}

public int getMaximum() {
    int max = grades[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
        if (grades[i] > grades[max])
            max = grades[i];
    }
    return max;

}

public int getMinimum() {
    int min = grades[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {

        if (grades[i] < grades[min])
            min = grades[i];
    }
    return min;
}

public String toString() {
    String returnString = "grades :";
    for (int i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
        returnString += grades[i];
    }
    return returnString;
}

public double getMedian() {
    double median = 0;

    if (grades.length % 2 == 0) {
        median = (grades[grades.length / 2] + grades[(grades.length / 2) + 1]) / 2;

    } else

        median = grades[((grades.length - 1) / 2) + 1];

    return median;
}

}
```

Comment: You need to look at your getMinimum method again, I don't think it's doing what you think it's doing

Comment: Also, getMaximum has the same problem, and I don't think you meant to write `sum = +grades[i];` in getAverage either

Comment: Your int min = grades[0]; in getMinimum could set min to say 50, if that's a valid grade. Then when you look up the minimum in the loop, you refer to grades[min], which will give you grades[50] - the 51st element of grades - which is almost certainly not what you want. Just putting grades[i] < min should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your constructor you declared a *local* variable `grades` which did not initialize your instance variable `grades`:

```
int [] grades = new int [numberofStudents];
```

So the instance variable `grades` remains `null`.  Try this:

```
grades = new int [numberofStudents];
```

which refers to the instance variable instead of declaring a local variable.

Comment: Thank You so much.. I have an another question. Does random generator create a lot of 0s. Most of my values are 0s.

Comment: Currently, you are sorting the array each time a value is set in the array.  That means that the default values (zeroes) that are still there will wind up in the beginning of the array.  Don't sort the array until all grades have been set.